# Maps between grassmannians with inclusion property

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, grassmannians

**Edit:** According to the comment of L. Spice I changed the inclusion sign to the subset sign.

Is there a continuous map $f:\mathbb{C}P^3 \to \textrm{Gr}_{\mathbb{C}}(2,4)$ with $x\subset f(x)$? What about a map $g$ in the opposite direction with $g(x)\subset x$? What about a holomorphic version ($f$ or $g$ holomorphic)? What about a generalization about such maps between arbitrary grassmannian spaces?

Comment: Shouldn't both '$\in$' be '$\subseteq$'?

Comment: @LSpice  yes thanks I revise it.

Comment: Note that giving a map $f$ as in the question is equivalent to giving a self-map of $P^3\mathbb C$ without fixed points.  (I don't know off the top of my head if such a thing exists, but I'll bet someone does.)

Comment: @LSpice the only complex projective space with fixed point property are $\mathbb{C}P^{2k}$. Please read the revise history of this question. I had changed $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to CP^3, based on the same reason you mentioned.

Comment: @LSpice I guess fixed point free maps in odd dimension is constructed linearly with a combination of 90 degree rotation and complex conjugation. But for quaternioun all projective space have FPP (both odd and even). This is proved in Hatcher book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no *holomorphic* such map. Consider the incidence variety $Z=\{(p,\ell)\in \mathbb{P}^3\times \mathbb{G}(2,4)\,|\, x\in\ell\} $.  The projection $p:Z\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{3}$ is a $\mathbb{P}^2$-bundle, in fact it is the projective tangent bundle to $\mathbb{P}^3$. You are asking for a section of this bundle; that would give a line bundle $M$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$ which is a subbundle of the tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{P}^3}$. Computing $c_3$ one sees that this line bundle must be $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(2)$; but $H^0(T_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-2))$ is zero, so $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(2)$ does not inject into $T_{\mathbb{P}^3}$.

I do not know if there exists a continuous section (contrary to what I wrote before editing).

Comment: @AliTaghavi seems to have [shown](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339060/maps-between-grassmanian-with-inclusion-property#comment848243_339064) how to correct my (initially (holomorphic, hence) wrong) [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/339064) to a continuous section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The map $f \mathrel: \ell \mapsto \ell \oplus \ell'$, where $\ell' = \mathbb C\cdot\overline{(b, -a, d, -c)}$ when $\ell = \mathbb C\cdot(a, b, c, d)$, satisfies your first condition.

(I originally had a version without the complex conjugation, which doesn't work because $\ell' = \ell$ when $\ell = \mathbb C\cdot(1, i, 1, i)$.  Fortunately [@AliTaghavi](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339060/maps-between-grassmanian-with-inclusion-property/339064#comment848243_339064) pointed out how to fix it.  The candidate without the conjugation would have been holomorphic, hence contradicted [@abx](https://mathoverflow.net/a/339074)'s answer.)

Comment: Very interesting!what about the  opposit direction?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, this answer is wrong (sorry!).  Please un-accept it so that I can delete it.

Comment: I do not see why it is wrong. Every fixed point free map $f$ works. you can revise it. i think we need  conjugation too $\bar{b}, -\bar{a},\bar{d}, -\bar{c}$. Yes?any way your effort really helped me. Am I mistaken to think that your $f$ can be revised?any way should I un-accept(after all)?

Comment: I unaccept the answer since you asked me so. but i still believe it can be revised .

Comment: I agree with your correction; thanks.  Actually it's a good thing, since the version without conjugation would have been holomorphic, hence contradicted [@abx](https://mathoverflow.net/a/339074)'s nice answer.